# how to send a data from page to another without change the screen?

Tags: flutter

i have a page named displayData . On it there is a button if i click on it it shows DraggableScrollableSheet normally it has a button done when i click on it the icon of the page on the bakground (DisplayData) must change .i used a variable in a setState   but it doesn't work it's true on the DraggableScrollableSheet but always false in display data
any help !

Comment: Have you ever heard of State Management? That's the solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you have and provide a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

for this type of cases, there are several solutions, I recommend the use of providers, in this way with the use of 'extends ChangeNotifier' you will be able to detect the changes made without having to use the setState and you will be able to call from any class (or page ) the variables you need

Answer (score 0):

you can use callback methods from on widget to another, if you have much complicated scenario then I suggest using state management libraries like Provider, RiverPod or Bloc.
also
Could you share your code here